# Linear Algebra True False: Inconsistency

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q. The system $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ is inconsistent if and only if  $rref(A)$ contains a row of zeros.

Answer is False.

But my answer was True because I was thinking of the following example.

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0
\end{array}\;\middle\vert\;\begin{array}{c}2\\3\\4\\9\end{array}\right)$$

Anybody has counter example for this? Or can prove that is false?
Help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, replace the $9$ by $0$. The resulting system is not inconsistent.